Converting straight from base $5$ to base $6$ without going to base $10$
Is it possible without going straight to base $_{10}$? For example, $4321_5 = ????_6$
I went with writing out $4321 = 4\cdot5^3+3\cdot5^2+2\cdot5^1+1\cdot5^0$
and then converting those numbers into base $_6$.
So $4\cdot125 = 500$, and $\frac{500}{6} = 83,2$ and I write down $2$. Second digit from the left, $3\cdot25 = 75$ + carry over $83 = 158$. $\frac{158}{6} = 26,2$, write down $2$, carry over $26$ etc. But then the number I get is wrong, $2201\neq 2414$, $2414$ being the correct solution.
Note: I know this is more of a programming question, but I am unsure whether or not other sites have LaTex installed.

At the microprocessor level you'd be using the same binary representation, then just rendering the number in some other base.  So, technically, just use assembly language is an answer to your question.  It's probably not what you meant, though.

If you do not want to compute the value in base 10 (nor in base 2 if using a computer...), you can just write everything explicitly, replacing $5$ with $6-1$, and ensuring that every coef is in the range $[0,5]$:
$$\begin{align}
{4321}_5 &= 4\times 5^3 + 3\times 5^2 + 2\times 5 + 1\\
&= 4(6-1)^3 + 3(6-1)^2+2(6-1)+1\\
&= 4(6^3-3\times 6^2+ 3\times 6-1)+3(6^2-2\times 6 +1)+2\times 6 -2 +1\\
&= 4\times 6^3+(-12+3)\times 6^2+(12-6+2)\times 6 +(-4+3-2+1)\\
&=4\times 6^3-9\times6^2+8\times 6 -2\\
&=4\times 6^3-9\times6^2+8\times 6-6+\underline{4}\\
&=4\times 6^3-9\times6^2+(6+1)\times 6+\underline{4}\\
&=4\times 6^3-9\times6^2+6^2+\underline 1\times 6+\underline{4}\\
&=4\times 6^3+(-2\times 6 + 4)\times6^2+\underline 1\times 6+\underline{4}\\
&=(4 -2)\times6^3+\underline 4\times6^2+\underline 1\times 6+\underline{4}\\
&=\underline 2\times 6^3+\underline 4\times6^2+\underline 1\times 6+\underline{4}\\
&= 2414_6
\end{align}$$

Thank you so much! Is this the method for doing it from any to any base by any chance?

The highest power of $6_{10}=11_{5}$ that goes into $4321_5$ is $6_{10}^3=1331_5$.
The highest multiple of $11_5^3=1331_5$ that goes into $4321_5$ is $\color{red}2\cdot1331_5=3212_5$, and $4321_5-3212_5=1104_5$.
The highest multiple of $11_5^2=121_5$ that goes into $1104_5$ is $\color{red}4\cdot121_5=1034_5$, and $1104_5-1034_5=20_5$.
The highest multiple of $11_5$ that goes into $20_5$ is $\color{red}1\cdot11_5$, and $20_5-11_5=\color{red}4_5$.
So, yes, the answer is $2414$.

We can convert from base $5$ to base $6$ the same way we convert from base $10$ to any other base.
Recall, if we want to convert a number from base $10$ to base $5$ for example, we continually divide until the quotient is less than $5$.
For example, let's convert $100$ from base $10$ to base $5$.
$$100\div 5=20\text{ with a remainder of }0$$ This gives $$20\text{ }0$$ so the last digit is $0$ and, since $20\gt 5$ we divide $20$ by $5$ to get $$4\text{ }0\text{ }0$$ and, since $4\lt 5$, we are done. The number $100$ is $400$ base $5$ which we can verify is $$4\times 5^2+0\times 5^1+0\times 5^0$$
To go to base $6$, we do the same thing with some tricky exceptions.

We must represent $6$ as $11$ because we are starting in base $5$.
When we do the division step, it is more difficult because we are usually unfamiliar with our multiplication tables in a different base.

Let's convert $400$ base $5$ to base $6$. Recall this is the number $100$ in base $10$ so we can check out work at the end.
$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{r}
                31  \\[-3pt]
11 \enclose{longdiv}{400} \\[-3pt]
     \underline{33}\phantom{2} \\[-3pt]
                20  \\[-3pt]
     \underline{11} \\[-3pt]
                4
\end{array}
$$
Notice that the arithmetic is base $5$ so, for example, $20-11=4$, not $9$.
This gives $$31\text{ } 4$$ and since $31\gt 11$, we continue.
$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{r}
                2  \\[-3pt]
11 \enclose{longdiv}{31} \\[-3pt]
     \underline{22}\phantom{} \\[-3pt]
                4 \\[-3pt]
\end{array}
$$ which gives $2\text{ }4\text{ }4$ and, since $2\lt 11$ (or $6$) since we are converting to base $6$, we get $244$ which can be verified to be $$2\times 6^2+4\times 6^1+4\times 6^0=72+24+4=100$$ base $10$.

My approach is to express $~6~$ as $~11_5~$ and then perform the following computations, completely in base $~5.~$
          3  4  2
    -------------
1 1 |  4  3  2  1
       3  3
       ----
       1  0  2
          4  4
       -------
             3  1
             2  2
             ----
                4

Result so far _ _ _ 4.

          3  1
    ----------
1 1 |  3  4  2
       3  3
       ----
          1  2
          1  1
       -------
             1  

Result so far _ _ 1 4.

          2  
    -------
1 1 |  3  1
       2  2
       ----
          4

Result so far _ 4 1 4.

       0  
    ----
1 1 |  2  
       0
       -
       2

Final Result 2 4 1 4 : a base 6 expression.


+1 for showing me a clever way to get around using Mathjax for long division. I basically hacked the example on the Mathjax page.
